# Identifying seperate websocket requests + spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am implementing WebSockets for the first time using spring boot. I would like some clarifications on web socket management.

1. Could I know an efficient way to differentiate separate WebSocket
   requests from the client and respond back correctly to the exact
   client who made that request? So when a request is received, we will
   put that session to a sessionMap in
   afterConnectionEstablished() and remove from the map when session is
   closed in afterConnectionClosed().
2. Now, upon getting a request, the service would build a response to
   give back to the socket. I would like to know how can I get the key
   (map id) to check if that session is available in the sessionMap and
   write to the socket if it is available and session.isopen
3. Should the WebSocket request have a unique ID in the request to
   match? So that only upon receiving it back, the client should be
   populating the data. Could anyone tell me how it is normally done?

Comment: The SendToUser  annotation could work...

Comment: Grasshopper, could you please elaborate? I am trying to figure out how the WebSocket sessions are managed and how each request for a specific data can be returned to the exact session that requested it.

Comment: This article explains it - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-sendtouser

Comment: @Grasshopper I was able to get the response without the HandshakeHandler code `setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
    // code
        }` in WebSocketConfig. Just used  
 `@MessageMapping("/totalsales")
 @SendToUser("/queue/totalsales")` in the controller. And worke`stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/totalsales", function (message)` from my client. However, even if I add this, how can I access the sessionId in the service or handler class?? Still not clear to me.

Comment: Did not work for me when followed this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590670/unable-to-get-the-response-from-convertandsendtouser-stomp-websocket-sprin) I'm missing something simple. **Typo in previous message** even if I add "handshake" code is what I meant